# pandas convert object to decimal(3,9)

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I've got a dataframe with column filled with a dtype: object. These values are retrieved from an asci file (position x + length y).

```
0       001191833837
1       001083340239
2       000716901420
3       001191833837
4       001191833837
            ...     
4162    001160715789
4163    001160715789
4164    001160715789
4165    000875149515
4166    001160715789
Name: WEGING, Length: 4167, dtype: object
```

These values should be interpreted as a number with 9 decimal places *(like decimal(3,9))*. How do I convert the dtype object to the desired result?

```
0       001.191833837
1       001.083340239
2       000.716901420
3       001.191833837
4       001.191833837
            ...     
4162    001.160715789
4163    001.160715789
4164    001.160715789
4165    000.875149515
4166    001.160715789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a float, use:

```
df['WEGING2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['WEGING']).div(10**9)
```

For a string:

```
df['WEGING3'] = df['WEGING'].str.replace(r'^(.{3})', r'\1.', regex=True)
```

output:

```
         WEGING   WEGING2        WEGING3
0  001191833837  1.191834  001.191833837
1  001083340239  1.083340  001.083340239
2  000716901420  0.716901  000.716901420
3  001191833837  1.191834  001.191833837
4  001191833837  1.191834  001.191833837
```